# Using SUM() result in query

Tags: mysql, sum

I have one little problem. I am using a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(...) AS result1, SUM(...) AS result2 FROM ...
```

and my question is how to use result1 and result2 in expression, something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(...) AS result1, SUM(...) AS result2, result1*100/result2 AS percentage FROM ...
```

---

Is there a way just use results of `SUM()` function or other?

I've tried just like this above, but this returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There 2 ways either you need to repeat the whole expression for sum or either use subselect

```
SELECT SUM(first_col) AS result1, SUM(second_col) AS result2 
SUM(first_col) * 100 /SUM(second_col) percentage 
FROM ...
```

Or a subselect

```
SELECT result1, result2 , result1*100/result2 AS percentage 
FROM (
SELECT SUM(first_col) AS result1, SUM(second_col) AS result2 
FROM ...
) t
```

Comment: Sounds great! But what if I have a few LEFT JOINS? It should be added at the end after subselect?

Comment: No your whole query should be in a subselect if you are going to use second approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery or you can repeat the expressions:

```
SELECT SUM(...) AS result1,
       SUM(...) AS result2, 
       SUM(...)*100/SUM(...) AS percentage
FROM ...
```

SQL doesn't allow you to refer to column aliases at the same level of a query.

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to just use the SUM() again,

so it would be:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(var1) AS result1, 
    SUM(var2) AS result2, 
    (SUM(var1)*100/SUM(var2)) AS percentage 
FROM ...
```

MySQL/SQL doesn't thus far allow you to use the custom columns you are making, they have to be defined columns in the database.